# How to flush the serial port struct serial_icounter_struct

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am working on serial communication with linux driver. In which I am using tcflush() call with TCIOFLUSH to flush port.

Also I am using serial_icounter_struct to get the port statistics of rx,tx,parity,overrun etc.

I want to clear the serial_icounter_struct when I do tcflush() with TCI0FLUSH, but it is flusing the tx and rx hardware buffer,but not clearing the serial_icounter_struct. I am still getting the previous tx and rx counts from serial_icounter_struct.

Could someone please help on flushing the serial_icounter_struct port statistics?

Thanks.